# Python pocketsphinx 'module' object has no attribute 'Decoder'

Tags: python, speech-recognition, cmusphinx, decoder, pocketsphinx

I try to run simple example of using pocketsphinx. I have installed all libraries, plugins that was needed... Python 2.7.6. But still get an error:

> pocketsphinx 'module' object has no attribute 'Decoder'

```
import sys,os 
import pocketsphinx as ps 
import sphinxbase


def decodeSpeech(hmmd,lmdir,dictp,wavfile):
    speechRec = ps.Decoder(hmm = hmmd, lm = lmdir, dict = dictp)
    wavFile = file(wavfile,'rb')
    wavFile.seek(44)
    speechRec.decode_raw(wavFile)
    result = speechRec.get_hyp()
    return result[0]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    hmdir = '/usr/share/pocketsphinx/model/hmm/wsj1'
    lmd   = '/usr/share/pocketsphinx/model/lm/wsj/wlist5o.3e-7.vp.tg.lm.DMP'
    dictd = '/usr/share/pocketsphinx/model/lm/wsj/wlist5o.dic'
    wavfile = "msg_12c3da80-c6be-11e3-9430-eb6ba5ab4d1f.wav"
    recognised = decodeSpeech(hmdir,lmd,dictd,wavfile)
```

Comment: Is this Python 3.x? Have you read https://github.com/bambocher/pocketsphinx-python#import?

Comment: Python 2.7.6. Yes i have done all instructions.

Comment: What does `print dir(ps)` show? `print ps.__file__`?

Comment: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pocketsphinx-0.0.4-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pocketsphinx/__init__.pyc

Comment: It looks like you're importing the right file, at least - and the `dir`?

Comment: I have viewed source of pocketsphin.py and he have ```Decoder``` class :(

Comment: That's not what I asked; *what does `print dir(ps)` show?!*

Comment: ['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__']

Comment: Then the error message isn't lying; `Decoder` isn't specified at the module level (i.e. in `__init__.py`). Why don't you try the `import` form *actually shown in the documentation*?

Comment: you mean: ```from sphinxbase import Config
    from pocketsphinx import Decoder``` ?

Comment: That's the one! It doesn't look like you're using anything else from `ps`.

Comment: I tried. Got the same error:

   ```from sphinxbase import Config
ImportError: cannot import name Config```

Comment: ```from pocketsphinx import Decoder
ImportError: cannot import name Decoder```

Comment: Well if you're using it as documented without success, why not raise it with the developer - https://github.com/bambocher/pocketsphinx-python/issues/new?

Comment: what you mean ? i tried this tutorial too: https://mattze96.safe-ws.de/blog/?p=640

Comment: I mean *this is possibly a bug*, so we can't help you fix it. If you've followed the instructions provided and are still having issues, open an issue on the project. Note that information about what precisely you've done will be helpful, in more detail than *"I have installed all libraries, plugins that was needed..."*

Comment: Have you tried to literally follow the import recipe form the [bottom of the readme](https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx-python)? They might have merged py 2.x and py 3.x import approaches at some moment.

Comment: yes:
```File "speech.py", line 9, in <module>
    from sphinxbase.sphinxbase import Config```

Comment: Now i'm trying to use python 3 and this code:

http://pastebin.com/m6PHWJ48

but get an error: ```TypeError: in method 'Decoder_decode_raw', argument 2 of type 'FILE *'```

Answer (score 0):

You are using old API in your code. New API implemented in pocketsphinx-python works like this:

https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx/blob/master/swig/python/test/decoder_test.py

Decoder is initialized with the help of configuration object. Models are also different.

Comment: can you give a example, how to upgrade it ?

Comment: Now i'm trying to use python 3 and this code:

http://pastebin.com/m6PHWJ48

but get an error: ```TypeError: in method 'Decoder_decode_raw', argument 2 of type 'FILE *'```

Comment: Python3 does not support file operations, you have to decode in streaming mode.

Comment: do you have an example ? i ran this one: http://sourceforge.net/p/cmusphinx/discussion/help/thread/ce372c57/#4d10/b3ea  but ```TypeError: in method 'Decoder_process_raw', argument 2 of type 'void const *'
```

Comment: This is because decoder was not created properly and there were earlier errors. For example it failed to load models. You can check logs for details.

Comment: In logs only "info" messages... I got models from here: https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx/tree/master/model/en-us

Comment: You can provide the log to get help on this issue.

Comment: Your code does not really make sense. You end utterance after processing 44 bytes and then continue while loop. Try to run existing example as is first, then do you modifications. I linked you the working demo above.

Comment: Yes i know that code does not make sense. But i want to show you the problem is in this line: ```decoder.process_raw(buf, False, False)``` it returns error: ```TypeError: in method 'Decoder_process_raw', argument 2 of type 'void const *'```. And the https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx/blob/master/swig/python/test/decoder_test.py  doesn't wok too !

Comment: ```# Decode streaming data.```

http://pastebin.com/UD30YMFJ

this code fails with error:
```TypeError: in method 'Decoder_process_raw', argument 2 of type 'void const *'```

Comment: on python 2, i have the issue from 1-st post